# Listview like button

Tags: android, listview

I use a Listview in my app, now I want to add a like button.

```
  public void likeButton(View view)

    {

        new PostComment().execute();

         }
```

**PostComment class**

```
 class PostComment extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Posting Comment...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
       int success;



        // Just random dummy data
        // I need to get the real values
        String user = "44";
        String post = "12";




        try {
            // Building Parameters
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", user));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("post_id", post));


            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            //Posting user data to script
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    POST_COMMENT_URL, "POST", params);

            // full json response
            Log.d("Post Comment attempt", json.toString());

            // json success element
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {

                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                Log.d("Comment Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

It works so far, the dummy data is added to my mysql database. But Instead of the dummy data:

```
        // Just random dummy data
        // I need to get the real values here
        String user = "44";
        String post = "12";
```

I want to get the real post_id of the specific post, in wich the button is clicked. Currently I display the post_id in the listview with a textview in the post. But how can I get this post_id to the String post = "";?

Comment: where you have stored these   user and post values ?

Comment: I get this data from a JSON request, they are stored like this JSONObject     obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
        Movie movie = new Movie();

        movie.setUsername(obj.getString("username"));
                        movie.setPOST_ID(obj.getString("post_id"));

                                

   


        // adding movie to movies array
        movieList.add(0, movie);

Comment: You need to  get those values from json feed and update the listview , is that your requirement ?